# Adding PointerDown/UpAnimation to Button control - Windows 8 XAML

Tags: animation, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to add the animate the button control using XAML.
Below is the style applied to the button.

```
<Style x:Key="ContentButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TapStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerUp">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However the animation does not work as expected.
Please advice on which approach should be used here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I like that you are using visual states. They make discreet animations like this easier in XAML. I think you will just need your own animations though. Should be pretty easy. Take the code below and drop it in any Windows 8 app page. Then open it in Blend so you can preview the visual states more easily. I think this is 90% of what you need. The rest is your custom scenario.

```
<UserControl>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ArrowButtonStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Left"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Right" >
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="180" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Up">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="90" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Down">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-90" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50">
        <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="20" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: the problem is that i'm not really used to the blend & my project contains references to the Player Framework and I'm not able to set the target platform to Any CPU which is automatically disabling the design view in both Blend & VS. I wanted to use the animation provided by the framework to keep it consistent with the build-in animations.

Comment: I completely understand. Just remove the player until you have the rest built and ready. I've hit the same wall.